# React: How to shift focus using arrow keys? (TreeView)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, shift, arrow-keys

I am looking for solution which allow to focus elements inside treeview using arrow keys.

Currently, I have treeView (ul) and treeNode  (li). Each treeNode may have their own treeView and so on. Every treeNode has `tabIndex="0"` property to add possibility navigate trough the treeView using `Tab` key. It works fine. But I would like to add keyboard arrow support to do the same thing.

Any idea how to do this?
P.S. I don't want to use any 3rd party libs expect pure React, JS.

```html
<section>
  <header>
    { title }
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <section>
        <header>
          { title }
        </header>
        <ul>
          // etc.
        </ul>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
<section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to move focus within treeView.
First of all you should find all your nodes inside your tree.
Then you can find focused element using `document.activeElement`. After that, you be able to find this item within your array nodes. (`document.activeElement == nodes[i]`) and remember index `i`. To move focus using arrow keys, just add `eventListener` to your node and handle it.

For example, to move upward you can do something like this:

`if(arrowUp) { elements[i + 1].focus() }`

Answer (score 1):

Roman's answer is helpful. I took this a step further by creating functions that handle moving focus up or down.

In the component I have my handleKeyDown function called on the onKeyDown event:

```
<UnorderedList id='unordered-list' onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
```

To call the functions I used an if statement like this below in my onKeyDown handler:

```
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        moveFocusDown()
    }
    if(e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        moveFocusUp()
    }
}
```

Next for the moveFocusDown function, I did the following:

```
    const moveFocusDown = () => {
    const listItems = document.querySelector('#unordered-list').childNodes
    const activeItem = document.activeElement
    for(let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

        const listLength = listItems.length
       if(activeItem === listItems[i] && activeItem !== listItems[listLength - 1]) {
        listItems[i + 1].focus()
       }
    }
}
```

The conditional `activeItem === listItems[i] && activeItem !== listItems[listLength - 1]` checks that the activeItem and the current index of the Unordered List child nodes are the same, then checks that the last element in the node list *isn't* the active element. This is needed to prevent moving focus to an element that doesn't exist.

The moveFocus up function is a little simpler:

```
    const moveFocusUp = () => {
    const listItems = document.querySelector('#menu').childNodes
    const activeItem = document.activeElement
    for(let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
       if(activeItem === listItems[i] && activeItem !== listItems[0]) {
        listItems[i - 1].focus()
       }
    }
}
```